# Google Analytics - Tracking PDFs in one site, but not the other?

Tags: pdf, google-analytics

so I have a bit of a dilemma here. I am pretty familiar with how GA tracks PDF either via adding tagging to each PDF, or by using Tag Manager...

I have two separate sites, with two unique UA-xxxxx-1 IDs...

One site, I can query back about 2 years, and see ".pdf" files as pageviews...

On another site, I try to query the same file extension and there is nothing, and i know for a fact PDFs are being downloaded via link clicks.

Why would one site show this and another is not?

They both utilize the same Universal script, I have not installed tag manager on these sites, but one shows PDFs and one does not?

Could there be something in the Admin section of the two sites in GA I need to look at?
Could something have been configured in one site, and not the other?

Am a bit confused by this...

Comment: Are both sites using same HTML structure? Can you post pdf links for both sites as comparison? Maybe something in the link is different and blocking GA.

Comment: I do not see anything different between the two sites, the HTML, or anything that would render the two links different. The PDFs that display as pageviews in Site 1 are shown as "/resources/location/file.pdf" essentially the path of the file location. Again, the GA code is the same for both sites, as we use a Content Management System that manages the code. Site 2 however, does not show any PDFs being listed in pageviews. Tag manager is not enabled on either site. Mystery continues.